# Output test classes run JUnit

Tags: java, junit, categories

I have several different packages of JUnit tests and they're all broken down by `@Category`. Is there a way to print out a list of all test classes and/or methods that get run at the end of running all the tests? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is in JUnit's domain, but I had a similar need and used AOP.  AOP was preferred since I could completely control what it displays.  My knowledge of this is limited to [Spring's AOP implementation.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/aop.html)

A good profiler is an option as well.